# Error while adding delegate to Action Dictionary using an out reference

Tags: c#, dictionary, delegates, out

It seems that adding a delegate to an `Action` stored into a `Dictionary` fails when I try do add it through the reference obtained using `TryToGetValue` method.

Here's an example reproducing the error:

```
void Foo()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Foo");
}
void Bar()
{   
  Console.WriteLine("Bar");
}

Dictionary<int, Action> dic = new Dictionary<int, Action>();    

dic[3] = delegate{};
dic[3] += Foo;

Action ac;
if (dic.TryGetValue(3,out ac))
{
  Console.WriteLine("Found");
  ac += Bar;
}
dic[3]();
```

Output:

```
Found
Foo
```

The value is found, but it seems that `ac` and `dic[3]` are references to different objects (`Bar` is not printed).

Could anyone explain me what's going on? With what exactly is filled the `out parameter`? Since `Action` are classes, shouldn't `ac` reference point to the same object stored into the `Dictionary`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example can be simplified (dictionary excluded):

```
  void Foo() {
    Console.WriteLine("Foo");
  }

  void Bar() {
    Console.WriteLine("Bar");
  }

  ...
  Action x = Foo;
  Action y = x;

  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
    Console.WriteLine("x was equal to y"); 

  // creates new delegate instance: 
  // x = x + Bar; 
  //   that is equal to 
  // x = Action.Combine(x, Bar);
  //   so x is not equal to y any longer:
  // x is a combined delegate (Foo + Bar)
  // y is a delegate to Foo (an old version of x)
  //   such a behavior is typical for operators (+, +=, etc.): 
  //   when we declare "public static MyType operator + (MyType a, MyType b)"
  //   it means that a new object "c" will be created that'll equal to sum of a and b 
  x += Bar; 

  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
    Console.WriteLine("x is still equal to y");

  y();
```

The output is:

> x was equal to y
>
> Foo

And the cause of such a behaviour is in the += operation algorithm

Comment: So basically Combine method returns a new istance of Action?

Comment: Yes. It's typical for operators (+ or += in this case)